# How to decide cut off?

Tags: quantiles

I will try my best to explain this simple doubt that I have. I have three responses (Increased, decreased and no change) and I have calculated the percentage for each. For instance, for X case- 46% showed an increase, 34% showed a decrease and 20% showed no change (similarly I have 12 such cases); now to state that 46% is a significant increase, how can I decide that? Or in some cases, it is a 46% increase, 47% decrease and 17% no change. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to analyze *X* case separately from the other cases, you will probably want to use something akin to a one-sample sign test.  You will want to compare the counts of e.g. "increase" and "decrease" to null counts.

You might want to ignore observations of "no change" and simply compare counts of "increase" and "decrease" to a 50% / 50% split of counts.  That is, if you had 12 increase, 10 no change, and 3 decease, you would compare 12 out of 15 with either a binomial test or a chi-square goodness of fit test. In R, `binom.test(12, 15)` or `chisq.test(c(12, 3))`.

Depending on your purpose, you might consider an analysis that includes counts of "no change" along with those of "increase" and "decrease".  You might group them: "decrease + no change" vs. "increase".  Or you might use all three counts.

If you want to analyze *X* case with e.g. *Y* case, *Z* case, and so on, you might look at logistic regression, for either a binomial dependent variable or a multinomial dependent variable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. In this case, even 'no change' is important as I am checking the effect of X. I thought of using a descriptive way to show how X could increase, decrease and even show no change. In this regard, I calculated the percentage. And wanted to state anything above this percent is a significant effect.

Comment: @SanjeetaSharmaPokharel ,  If there is some percent increase that you consider practically important, then you could use that as a cutoff.  But I wouldn't use the term "significant" as that usually suggests statistical significance.  You might also look at odds ratio, comparing the percent increase and decrease.  You might also look at Cohen's *h*.  For these, you can use percentages.  However, if you want to conduct a hypothesis test  to determine if the increase is "statistically significant", you'll probably have to use the original ***counts*** of increase and decrease.

Comment: This helped, thank you @SalMangiafico :)